# mod_rewrite redirect to wrong dir

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a simple redirect :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^test.php$ index.php
```

in my htaccess file located in : root_dir/my_site/my_section/test.php

The problem is that it is redirecting to root_dir/index.php instead of root_dir/my_site/my_section/index.php

How do i redirect to the same folder ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your RewriteBase to

```
RewriteBase /my_site_/my_section
```